# Grails Ajax Login

Tags: ajax, grails, spring-security

I want to take use of the ajax login feature of the spring security plugin.

I am completely stuck getting a JSON success response from the loginController into my GWT client.

As I understood from the documentation I need to post my params to the url /j_spring_security_check and spring security is redirecting me to the right action.

If I look into my LoginController I see nothing of the actual login logic and its a bit magic for me where all the login/db stuff is done. Further spring security always redirects to action auth instead of using AjaxAuth even if I add the header "X-Requested-With" to post. If I do my post to the url /login/ajaxAuth I am getting a 401 which is OK because its written down in the controller(even if i dont know why we need to return a 401 here). Maybe I am doing something completely wrong :-)

My basic questions are:

- Where can I find the login logic?
- What parameter do I have to provide?
- Which URL do I have to use?
- What do I have to do if I dont want to use the username but instead and email field?

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're correctly implemented it, maybe there some small bug, like a typo.

Btw:

1. It's [implemented at filter](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/security-filter-chain.html), that process your request before actual controllers. At your case it will be `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` (or `RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter`). Controller is used there only to render an additional data. As for ajax auth, it uses `/login/ajaxSuccess`, that renders a `JSON` response
2. By default it uses `j_username` & `j_password`. And you can use `ajax=true` parameter, instead of `X-Request-With` header
3. `/j_spring_security_check` by default
4. You can implement your own `GrailsUserDetailsService` (or extend `GormUserDetailsService`), and [setup it as a spring bean](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/14.%20Grails%20and%20Spring.html), with name `userDetailsService`, at `resources.xml`

You can also turn on logging for Spring Security by:

```
log4j {
   debug 'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity',
         'org.springframework.security'
}
```

maybe it will be helpful

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. I tried now several ways and now i am getting the point :-). I was not adding the parameter instead I was posting a JSON Object which Grails couldnt parse. I have one further question. How do I handle the remember me functionality? I create a cookie on client side with gwt but is it possible to let it create by grails and store it on the client?

Answer (score 2):

I am using *Grails 2.1.1* and ran into this same issue. Tried all the above things but still couldnt get my AJAX login to call the `ajaxSuccess` method.
However when it failed it was calling `authFail?ajax=true`.

After digging in more, here is what I did:

1. Added `grails.plugins.springsecurity.successHandler.targetUrlParameter = 'ajaxUrl'` in my Config.groovy
2. Added `<input type="hidden" name="ajaxUrl" value="/login/ajaxSuccess" />` in my AJAX login form

Not sure why it fixed, but it seemed to work for me.

Just posting this solution for users who get stuck and come to this ticket for solution.